# Uber OAuth 2.0 Credentials Refreshing Issue - Uber example

Tags: python-2.7, uber-api

Thank you for the great community, been a lot of help :).

I tried the simple example in the rides-python-sdk and I added the needed information in the "config.yaml" file and I got the right credentials in the "oauth2_session_store.yaml". I managed to request a ride with sandbox enabled and everything works like a charm.

Problem is 4 to 5 days later when I try to request a ride, I get 401: Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.

Under the "Authorization" section in the README.rst file it is stated that

> The SDK will handle the token refresh for you automatically when it
>   makes API requests with an UberRidesClient.

Am I missing any steps that I am not aware of ? or is this an issue with the example ?

P.S.: I am using Uber-rides-python-sdk version 0.2.4.

P.P.S: The expires in seconds field is 1490314576. Which roughly equals 17249 days, therefore I think within that period the access token remains valid.

Comment: I think this is an issue with the example. The example doesn't save the updated refresh token. If you remove the token store and try again it will work as expected after the login.

Comment: Thank you, Dustin. I do not think it is practical to login each time I need to refresh the token. How do I save the updated refresh token ? Also, the "expires in seconds" field was not exceeded. Should not the access token be valid ?

Comment: You create a github issue or even better a pull request to add token refreshing to the example. Otherwise, I will add it to our backlog and follow up when I implement (no immediate plans).